# different values on evaluating an expression in c in float and int representation?

Tags: c, postfix-notation, mathematical-expressions

on changing this expression to postfix representation and then evaluating it.. I'm getting 17.8 as answer.. if "n" would have been of float type then there is no problem in answer. since n is a variable of integer type, digits after decimal oint should be truncated and answer should be 17 but the output is 15. how?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

int i=3,a=4,n;
float t =4.2;
n=a*a/i+i/2*t+2+t;
printf("n = %d\n",n);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: the debugger can tell you everything you need, why do you ask us?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath i've never used debugger. can you plz explain me about that?

Comment: I hope you used a search engine before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm getting 17.8 as answer.. if "n" would have been of float type then there is no problem in answer.

No. You can't. You will get `17.833332` if your expression would be

```
n=a*a*1.0/i+i/2.0*t+2+t;
```

See:

```
a*a/i = (4*4)/3 = 16/3 = 5 
i/2*t = (3/2)*4.2 = 1*4.2 = 4.2
2 + t = 2 + 4.2 = 6.2
```

`5 + 4.2 + 6.2 = 15.4` which will truncated to `15`.

Comment: can u please explain the logic for this 1 as well...
float a=1.5;
int b=3;
a=b/2+b*8/b-b+a/3;

Comment: @user3725723; If you got the answer then you should be able to do that for yourself. Apply same logic.

Comment: I tried but I'm getting 7 as answer.. but output is 6.500000
c postfix notation is b2/b8*b/+b-a3/+
=> {(b/2)+[(b*8)/b]}-b+(a/3)
=>{(1.5)+[(24)/3]}-3+(.5)
=>{(1.5)+8}-2.5 = 7
Do I need to evaluate b/2 as 1 (I assumed so because b is an integer) but the variable, that we are evaluating is a float value then b/2 should be equal to 1.5!